# Android Studio: can't edit files after a while

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio and I have a problem:

after some time of work, I'm not able to edit files anymore, I have to restart the IDE to edit them for a while again.

That's very annoying. Is there a way to solve this? I saw others on google having almost the same problem (mostly on ubuntu), but I wasn't able to find any solution except a temporary one: if I click on the scrollbar of the file I'm able to edit it again, but the problem will be triggered again if I change file or do anything else outside of it; so the actual problem it's the editor not getting the focus by clicking on it.

I'm on Windows 8.1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407869/android-studio-cant-edit-files

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=124715

Comment: yes I already seen those, but seem not entirly my case. android studio it's not on readonly mode and I can open files normally, edit XMLs but not java files

I'm on windows 8

Comment: what version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @Henry the very last one, 1.4 I think I can't check now

Comment: Please check that if this is happening after pressing some key combination, like alt+left/right (to change tab)

Comment: @robodev absolutely not. they just lose focus after the IDE stay inactive for some time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My robotics team had this problem before on Windows 7. It has been a while, so I don't remember exactly how (this was years ago), but we had found that the problem was related to the project files being in a google drive and the syncing process would make Android Studio lock the files into read-only mode. the workaround we found was to take the files out of the drive folder and use a version control system.

Comment: It's probably what happened back then.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you are using Ubuntu OS.

As given [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68530)

> The bug seems to be triggered by some missing synchronization between
>   IBus (the server) and Xlib + AWT (the client JVM), exposed by a
>   combination of a quick succession of key presses and the client’s
>   slower event handling. The bug has already been reported upstream:

the bug is already reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68530)

The 2 workarounds that helped me were :

> **Workaround #1:** Force ibus in synchronous mode
>
> ```
> $ IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1 ibus-daemon -xrd
> ```
>
> Do this preferably before starting Studio. This workaround was
>   suggested in https://code.google.com/p/ibus/issues/detail?id=1733 for
>   a different Java application facing the same problems.
>
> **Workaround #2:** Disable IBus input in Studio
>
> ```
> $ XMODIFIERS= ./bin/studio.sh
> ```
>
> This will only disable input methods for Studio, not the other
>   applications. Restarting the daemon while Studio is running
>   (‘ibus-daemon -rd’) effectively disables the input methods for all
>   other applications, and can also crash Studio's JVM with a
>   segmentation fault.

Comment: I'm on windows not Ubuntu.

Comment: @Elltz actually I asked OS information by commenting to the question. Since he didnt reply, I posted this answer :-)

Comment: Can I make the workaround #2 persist across restart?

Comment: Yes... it should.. but I think the issue is not happening anymore.. they might have fixed it already